# MongoDB: Converting field type from String to Array

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I used mongoimport to import an csv file. This dataset to be specific:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1d7Qps--r0i-E4drYQQzntSdXN8xJ4-6qk24CiMed#map:id=3

The problem I am having is with the `description` field.

```
[{"landing_point_id":3522,"latlon":"51.898325,-8.472768","name":"Cork, Ireland"}]
```

I figure this is an array of objects so I am making a mongoose model for it like this:

```
  description: [{
    landing_point_id: Number,
    latlon: String,
    name: String
        }],
```

But this gives me an empty array. If I set the type of `description` to `String` I do get the values – but of course as a string, so the properties are not accessible.

```
"description" : "[{\"landing_point_id\":8398,\"latlon\":\"52.207114,1.620294\",\"name\":\"Sizewell, United Kingdom\"}]"
```

So the problem seem to be that the field `description` is a `String` when I would like it to be an `Array`.

Following answers on here I have tried to convert it from string to array, but with no luck.

```
db.cables.find().snapshot().forEach(function (el) {
  el.description_array = [ el.description ];
  db.cables.save(el);
});
```

This just wraps the string in another array.

```
"description_array" : [ "[{\"landing_point_id\":8398,│    col10: '',
\"latlon\":\"52.207114,1.620294\",\"name\":\"Sizewell, United Kingdom\"}]" ]
```

And the same for

```
  el.description_array = new Array(el.description);
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Something that could be edited in the csv file before importing to make mongoimport interpret it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "string" now needs to be "parsed" into a valid data structure. Also the "latlong" will be useless to you as both a "string" itself and in the wrong order for how MongoDB expects the coordinates.

So we fix both:

```js
var bulk = db.cables.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.cables.find({ "description": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.description = JSON.parse(doc.description);
    doc.description = doc.description.map(function(desc) {
        desc.coordinates = desc.latlon.split(",").reverse().map(function(el) { 
            return parseFloat(el);
        });
        delete desc.latlong;
        return desc;
    });

    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "description": doc.description }
    });
    count++;

    // Send batch one in 1000
    if (count % 1000 == 0) {
       bulk.execute();
       bulk = db.cables.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

// Clear any queued
if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Change your mongoose schema to this:

```js
"description": [{
    "landing_point_id": Number,
    "coordinates": [],
    "name": String
}],
```

And now you have data you can index and use with GeoSpatial queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And also for the help with the coordinates (was the next thing on my to-fix list).